# DS3231 on Battery Power and Use of Aging Register

Tags: arduino, datasheet, rtc, atmega328p

Currently working with  DS3231M RTC module with Arduino Uno and also creating a library for this. It is working perfectly but I have a doubt that DS3231M work on both VCC(main current) and VBAT (i.e the battery). So when I switch off the power from VCC it is not possible to communicate from microcontroller to the DS3231M through I2C just want to know why it is happening, is it the normal behaviour of the chip or I am doing something wrong?

Also if anyone can please explain the use of Aging Register in the chip and how it can be helpful to adjust time. Here is the data sheet [DS3231M Datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231M.pdf). But there it is written, " Use of the Aging Offset register is not needed to achieve the accuracy as defined in the Electrical Characteristics tables."

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The battery supply is intended principally to keep the timekeeping going while the main supply is absent. It is possible to use I2C while the clock is powered by VBATT, but the load on the battery increases considerably. (It is unclear from the data sheet if the local I2C pullup resistors are powered in this mode from the battery or from another source.) In any case, if there is power to run I2C then it is clearly better to use this to power the DS3231.

The Aging Offset register allows the timebase to be adjusted as an offset from the factory calibrated value. Unless you have a VERY accurate time reference, I suggest that you should leave this alone.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have already checked with a multimeter that in the VBATT mode, the local I2C pull-up registers are not powered from the VBATT, I think that's why it is not communicating on I2C in VBATT mode. So if the pull-up registers are connected to Power in both mode then is it possible to communicate in I2C on VBATT?

Comment: I understand that the Aging Offser register is used to adjust time but in the Datasheet, on page 15 it is saying that "Use of the Aging Offset register is not needed to achieve the accuracy as defined in the Electrical Characteristics tables." that confuses me. So can you please explain that in details that will be helpful. In which type of scenario this Aging Register is used. Thank you.

Comment: @HimadriGanguly The DS3231 will meet its advertised specifications (e.g. +/- 5ppm for the DS3231M) under all conditions specified in the datasheet. In general, it's a "set it and forget it" device. However, crystals (but not the MEMS oscillator in the M variant) age over time and their properties change. By tuning the aging register while comparing the device against a precision reference (e.g. an atomic clock or GPS-disciplined oscillator) you can achieve even better accuracy. I can get <0.5ppm from the crystal-based DS3231 with proper tuning.

Comment: @HimadriGanguly In general, though, it's not terribly important or necessary to adjust the aging register unless you have a particular reason to do so.

Comment: @heypete thank you for the explanation and the help. Cheers buddy. I have developed the DS3231 library for Arduino and you can find it at https://github.com/himadriganguly/Himadri_DS3231. Please have a look at the library and give your feedback if i have done anything wrong.

Comment: @HimadriGanguly: I haven't had a chance to thoroughly review it, but it looks reasonably good overall. Also, keep in mind that the DS3231 and DS3231M, though differing in only a single letter, are different devices. The non-M variant has a crystal, the buffered output of which is available on the 32kHz pin (+/- 2ppm), and can output various fixed-frequency square waves, while the M variant has a MEMS oscillator and can only output a square wave at 1 Hz. The 32 kHz output on the M version is derived from some internal state, but can vary by as much as 2.5%.

Comment: @heypete thanks for your time to check the repo. Definitely i will keep your suggestions in mind. But can you just briefly tell me what is the main difference between crystal and MEMS oscillator and which one is more accurate and better.

Comment: @HimadriGanguly Good question. The crystal is more stable, has simple low-power supporting electronics, but requires a bit more handling to attach to the main chip in the DS3231. The crystal is more susceptible to vibration and impact, so it can't be used in all environments. The MEMS oscillator is easier to make and integrate using the same process used to make the rest of the chip, but requires more electronics on the chip to work. The MEMS oscillator is much more vibration-resistant, but is also much more sensitive to temperature.

Comment: @HimadriGanguly The temperature-correction system on both chips makes it less of an issue, but it's not as precise as the variant that uses the crystal. What is "better" depends on the use case. For me, I prefer the ones with a crystal, but your needs may be different. For typical uses as an RTC on a computer or other such device, the differences are negligible and either could be used.

Comment: @heypete Thanks a lot buddy for taking your time to answer all the query. Take care.